# NullPointer in app purchase blling sample

Tags: android

I am using the android.test.purchase in my app billing. The first time I purchase, it was successful. But in the second time it crashes.

```
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497): Process: com.example.sampleApp, PID: 2497
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.codemagnus.finalsip.AdapterAndRowItems.DrinkCredits_Adapter$1.onClick(DrinkCredits_Adapter.java:119)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-30 11:42:12.276: E/AndroidRuntime(2497):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Code:

```
String thisResponse = listResponse.get(position);
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                        String sku = object.getString("productId");

                    if(sku.equals(((BaseActivity)context).inappid)){
                        Bundle buyIntentBundle = ((BaseActivity)context).mservice
                                .getBuyIntent(3, ((BaseActivity)context).getPackageName(), sku,
                                        "inapp",
                                        "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                                .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

                        ((BaseActivity)context).startIntentSenderForResult(
                                pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                                new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                    }
```

please help. thanks :)

Comment: what is DrinkCredits_Adapter line 119?

Comment: I know its your class, you have a NullPointerException at line 119 of DrinkCredits_Adapter

Comment: that line point this code pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,

Comment: in that case either context or pendingIntent are null I would imagine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this simple code.

```
String purchaseToken = "inapp:"+((BaseActivity)getActivity()).getPackageName()+":android.test.purchased";
                    try {
                        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).mservice.consumePurchase(3, ((BaseActivity)getActivity()).getPackageName(), purchaseToken);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Add this code in your onActivityResult and in the code before you call Purchase intent. Cheers!